# How to set LANG when creating a bundle with PyInstaller

Tags: python-3.x, macos, bundle, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I'm creating an application with **PyQt5** (5.10) and **Python** 3.6.
I'm using **PyInstaller** to bundle my application. On **MacOS**,
PyInstaller creates a directory named `dist` which contains an executable `myapp` and the bundle `myapp.app`.
The executable runs perfectly.
The bundle `myapp.app` runs well, but when I'm inserting accented characters, as `é` into an input widget, the application crashes with the error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xe9' in position 63: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The `myapp.app` just contains the executable `myapp` which runs as I expect.

I've tested to run `myapp` with an empty environment:

```
env -i ./myapp
```

I get the same error that `myapp.app`.

With a `LANG` defined:

```
env -i LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8 ./myapp
```

No errors.

So, I now know that the problem is related to `LANG environment variable`.

Now, my question is:

How to create my bundle to allow `myapp.app` to access the LANG environment variable?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Here is my PyInstaller spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-

import os
import sys

block_cipher = None

if os.name == 'nt':
    icon = 'images/icon.ico'
elif sys.platform == 'darwin':
    icon = 'images/icon.icns'
else:
    icon = None

a = Analysis(['../main.py'],
             pathex=['.'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
          cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries,
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='My App',
          debug=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=False,
          runtime_tmpdir=None,
          console=False, icon=icon)
app = BUNDLE(exe,
             name='My App.app',
             icon=icon,
             bundle_identifier='com.me.myapp',
             info_plist={
                 'NSHighResolutionCapable': 'True'
             },)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a solution to my problem.

I don't know exactly why it crashed but, instead of printing `str(my_value)`, I send it into a log file with the logging module, and there is no longer any crash.

`sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `utf-8` so it will remain a mystery... So I guess it must be related to encoding and stdio problem.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered same problem, instead of output to log file. I reconfigure utf-8 of stdout as following command:

sys.stdout.reconfigure(encoding='utf-8')

Maybe it can resolve your problem.

Comment: BTW, because macOS execute .app with a new shell, so the environment is different